# Using validation on a form where more than one model means asp.net core C #

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core

There are 18 models (classes C #) in which the customized validation (Required, stringLength, Display, DataType and etc). For these models, the form of adding / changing is automatically generated in order not to produce 18 * 2 identical in essence forms.

Data on the form is displayed with the help of "ViewBag.Model". Data fields themselves are output in a loop using an array of properties "ViewBag.Properties". The name of the columns, depending on the language of the array "ViewBag.Columns". Type of generated field: number, date, text, array types "ViewBag.TypeList".
How can I not use javascript, use the basic customized validation of each model?
Page code:

```
    @using System.Reflection;

    <style>
        .adminFormControl {
            padding: 0px 50px 0px 50px;
            max-width: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            min-height: 38px;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>

    <div style="text-align: -webkit-center;">
        <h4>
            @ViewBag.Method
        </h4>
        @if (ViewBag.Method == NanoWiki.Resources.Translations.Add)
        {
            <p>
                @NanoWiki.Resources.Translations.IgnoredId
            </p>
        }
        <hr />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <form asp-action="Apply" asp-controller="Admin" asp-route-Table="@ViewBag.Table" asp-route-Method="@ViewBag.Method" asp-route-Page="@ViewBag.Page"
                      data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-success="AjaxLoad" data-ajax-update="#PartialViewId">
                    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

                    @for (int i = 0; i < ViewBag.Columns.Count; i++)
                    {
                        <div class="form-group adminFormControl" style="text-align: left;">
                            @Html.Label(ViewBag.Properties[i].Name, ViewBag.Columns[i], new { @class = "control-label" })
                            <input class="form-control adminFormControl" type="@ViewBag.TypeList[i]" value="@ViewBag.Properties[i].GetValue(ViewBag.Model, null)"
                               name="@ViewBag.Properties[i].Name" />
                    </div>
                }

                <div class="form-group adminFormControl">
                    <input type="submit" value="@NanoWiki.Resources.Translations.Save" class="btn btn-default adminFormControl" />
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a asp-action="ListView" asp-controller="Admin" asp-route-Table="@ViewBag.Table" asp-route-Page="@ViewBag.Page"
           data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-update="#PartialViewId">
            @NanoWiki.Resources.Translations.Back
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <script src="~/js/adminPage.js"></script>
}
```

Comment: What kind of behaviour are you seeing here? Is there an error? Is the javascript not in the final HTML?

Comment: Nothing. I press "Save" without data and form send empty model for contoller

Comment: In the "adminPage.js" file there is no validation

Comment: I mean, if you inspect the HTML before pressing "Save", what do you see? Is the javascript added?